# How to change background color of an HTML displayed table in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I use the functions *display(HTML(html-string))* to display an HTML formatted table in my notebook. However, trying some css to change the table background color is not being honored. Here is a snipit of my code:

```
rownum = 1
# make this table yellow
source = '<table bgcolor="yellow"><tr><th>Number</th><th>Instance Type</th><th>Total Cost</th>' \
    '<th>Number of Instances</th></tr>'

for k in keys: 
    source += "<tr><td>%d</td><td>%s</td><td>$%0.2f</td><td>%d</td></tr>" % \
          (rownum,resultsTable2[k]["itype"],k,resultsTable2[k]["num"])
    rownum += 1

source += '</table>'
display(HTML(source))
```

**Output looks like this:**
[image: example output]

**Version Details**

The version of the notebook server is 4.4.1 and is running on:
Python 2.7.12 (default, Sep 28 2016, 18:41:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)]

Firefox 53.0.3 on OS X Sierra.

Comment: bummer - display(HTML()) is not exportable via PDF.